# Is there a way to create 'add to cart' in ecommerce website without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

my fellow problem solvers. Hopefully, you have a productive day. I am working on an e-commerce website project whereby I do it by using Laravel 8. So far I have reached a point to create 'add to cart' so as customers could do shopping. By reading different tutorials I am grateful that I can add products to the cart, edit and update them also deleting. But I want it to work without refreshing the page. I used Jquery to create Ajax requests as a lot of tutorials suggested. I think it will be simple for you to understand and help if I will show my codes.

here is my 'add to cart' link

```
<li class="add_to_cart"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-tippy="Add to cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $product->productID ?>)" data-tippy-placement="top" data-tippy-arrow="true" data-tippy-inertia="true"> <span class="lnr lnr-cart"></span></a></li>
```

Here is Ajax and Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
 });
    
function quickview(id) {
        
    $.get('/quickview/'+id, function (response) {
        if (response) {
            $("#id").html(response.id);
            $("#brand").html(response.brand);
            $("#productname").html(response.product_name);
            $("#price").html(response.price);
            $("#description").html(response.product_context);
            $("#img").attr('src',response.image);
        }
    })
}

function addtocart(id) {
    var _url = '/product/add-to-cart/'+id;

    $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', 
            id: id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            window.location.reload();
            // I think here is where I stuck,
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });           
}
</script>
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/product/add-to-cart/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('add.to.cart')->middleware('loggedin');
```

Here is controller

```
public function addToCart($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $cart = session()->get('cart', []);
    
    if(isset($cart[$id])) {
        $cart[$id]['quantity']++;
    } else {
        $cart[$id] = [
                     "name" => $product->product_name,
                     "quantity" => 1,
                     "price" => $product->price,
                     "maelezo" => $product->product_context,
                     "image" => $product->image
         ];
    }
       
    session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return response()->json(['success' => true]);

    // return response()->json($cart);
    //return response()->json($cart);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what you specific problem is, currently you have just given us progress report

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Thanks. I want to be able to add products to cart, without refreshing the page. So the problem is page is refreshing when i add, delete , edit and update my cart.

Comment: I think you may need to add a `preventDefault();` to stop the form doing its default action of submitting

Comment: yes you need work with and SPA arquitecture and use ajax to request data from server. you must know that need implement more javascript to get best user interaction with the ui...

Comment: I have just add event.preventDefault(); but the page still refreshing @RiggsFolly

Comment: Where did you add it

Comment: in my jquery,  function addtocart(id){}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this would be removing `href` attribute from `anchor` tag.

```
<li class="add_to_cart">
  <a data-tippy="Add to cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $product->productID ?>)" data-tippy-placement="top" data-tippy-arrow="true" data-tippy-inertia="true"> 
    <span class="lnr lnr-cart"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Other solution would be changing anchor tag with buttons or, a simple span {custom designed button}.

```
<button onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $product->productID ?>)">add to cart </button>
```

Adding button inside form or `input type='submit'` will submit the form so be aware of that.

How it works

```js
function showmsg1(){
  document.getElementById("msg").innerText = 'hello, you clicked button without refresh';
}

function showmsg2(){
  document.getElementById("msg").innerText = 'hello, you clicked button now it will refresh, this is hell...!';
}
```

```html
<h1> hello, wassup</h1>

<h3> click on buttons </h3>

<span> Without refresh: </span> <a onclick="showmsg1()"> <button>click me</button></a><br/>

<span> With refresh: </span><a onclick="showmsg2()" href=""> <button> click me </button> </a><br/>

<span id="msg"></span>
```

Comment: Good details @MohammedKhurram. But the issue is, my session stores data very well when customer add an item to CART except it does not echo those data the same time until i refresh the page. So the session is able to store details of even more than five items without refreshing the page but the session can't echo them unless i refresh the whole page. Here is where I stuck

Comment: @John I can understand your problem now as you have briefly explained it. the solution for that would be, creating new file containing design of cart, then loading it onto the division of base page whenever ajax call is successful, did you get it?, if you need some example code I can write one.

Comment: please show me some codes

Answer (score 0):

Answering in accordance with your comment on my previous answer.

Working example [here](https://koding-khurram.herokuapp.com/stackoverflow/questions/69437459/)

Sample HTML

```
    Click on buttons<br/>
    
    <span>Item btn1  <button onclick="addtocart(this)" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" value="btn1">Add to/Remove from cart</button></span><br/><br/>
    <span>Item btn2  <button onclick="addtocart(this)" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" value="btn2">Add to/Remove from cart</button></span><br/><br/>
    <span>Item btn3  <button onclick="addtocart(this)" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn3" value="btn3">Add to/Remove from cart</button></span><br/><br/>
    <span>Item btn4  <button onclick="addtocart(this)" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn4" value="btn4">Add to/Remove from cart</button></span><br/><br/>
    <span>Item btn5  <button onclick="addtocart(this)" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn5" value="btn5">Add to/Remove from cart</button></span><br/><br/>
    <div id="sessions"></div>
```

Script

```
//Laoding the dynamic page on document ready
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sessions").load("showSession.php");
});
//function to add to cart 
function addtocart(e){
  val = e.value;
  $.post("sessions.php",{type: "addtocart", value : val},function(data, status){
    if(status == "success"){
      $("#sessions").load("showSession.php");//Laoding the dynamic page once added/removed
    }
  });
}
```

For any queries comment down.

Comment: your approach is everything I wanted. Thanks to everyone for your contribution, I real appreciate.

Comment: You may consider upvoting/accepting answer for future reference, it helps others :) @John